# opcache preload in wamp

Tags: php, apache, preload, opcache, php-7.4

I tried to use the PHP 7.4 new feature `opcache.preload` in [wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/?lang=en). But Apache could not start. I did check Apache error log, PHP error, and Windows event log for useful error but I did not see any error. Apache did not simply start. What could be the problem? I am using Windows 7 ultimate SP1 (64bit). My `preload.php` content can be viewed [here](https://pastebin.com/9S9t2AsM). I put the `preload.php` file on the root directory of my localhost site which runs on virtual host. My setup structure is like below:

```
D:/Server/ all wamp server files and folder
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName lws.dev
      DocumentRoot "F:/mysite/Public"
      <Directory  "D:/mysite/Public/">
         Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
       </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Site location

```
 F:/mysite/
    App/
    core/
    Public/   preload.php
    vendor/
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, preload is not supported in Windows. See the documentation in the link below;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.preloading.php